# I want to creat backup of my etc/httpd on a remote server using mysql and mysqldump

Tags: linux, shell, mysql-backup

i want to backup my files from /etc/httpd on a remote server with IP=xxx to my dir. /tmp. Ive got password and name of it. Created backup should be compressed and named httpd-day-month-year-hour-minute-sec.tar.bz2 . I tried

```
FILE=httpd.sql. `date +"%d%m%Y_%H%M%S"`
DBSERVER=xxx
DATABASE=/etc/httpd
USER=uzivatel
PASS=password

mysqldump --opt --protocol=TCP --user=${USER} --password${PASS} --host=${DBSERVER} ${DATABASE} > ${FILE}

bunzip $FILE

echo"${FILE}.bz hotovo:"
ls-l ${FILE.bz}
```

I know there are many mistakes but i am fairly new to scripting and problems are in FILE coomand not dounf in mysqldump ambiguous redirect. thanks

Comment: sorry for mistake dir. /tmp is on the remote server its not mine

Comment: Where are you stuck? Did you get any errors?

Comment: ./sql.sh: line 3: 28102016_090119: command not found
./sql.sh: line 9: ${FILE}: ambiguous redirect
./sql.sh: line 11: bunzip: command not found
.bz hotovo:
ls: cannot access .bz: No such file or directory

Comment: line 3 is File line lien 9 is mysqldumo line

Comment: Is your script named as **sql.sh**? What **shell** are you running this in? What **OS** are you on (just making sure you are not on windows)? Do you see the **$FILE** getting created after running the mysqldump? Use a command like **set -x** and/or **set -v** to see verbose output and values of shell variables as your commands get executed. Put a space after your **echo** statement (between echo and double-quote. I don't see a space there). Same thing with "ls-l" (space between ls and -l).

Comment: ive got it all wrong i shoudnt be using mysql its just files not a database... so what is the other way i would use tar then ssh and rsync but am not sure with the syntax

Comment: Ok. Then your objective is just to gzip a file and transfer it securely to the other machine. You can read examples of gzip/gunzip from tutorials. You may need help from your administrator in setting up configuration for secure file transfer (if this is the first time you are using secure file transfer).